# How can I get a function in Python 3 to return a value that I can use in another function?

Tags: python, function, return, indentation, dice

I need to design a game of snakes and ladders in python and for part of it, I need to be able to roll a dice and get a random value. For this, I have imported random and then written the function below. However, obviously, I then need to be able to use the dice value in other functions of the game. How do I get it so that the value python returns is retained and able to be used in another function.

Below is the function I have written for rolling the dice. However, when I then run this function and then afterwards try `print(dice_value)`, the program tells me that `dice_value` has not be defined.

Anybody able to help??

```py
import random 
def roll_dice():
    dice_value = random.randint(1,6)
    print("Its a..." + str(dice_value))
    return dice_value
```

Comment: okay, clearly I don't know how to use this website because it didn't format my code properly in my question. anybody able to help with that either?

Comment: Please update your question with the way in which you call your function and print the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `dice_value` exists only inside your function `roll_dice()`. It is a **local variable**.
You need to call your function with:

```
my_variable = roll_dice()
```

Now the result of your function is stored in the variable `my_variable`, and you can print it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the return value somewhere and then use it or pass it to another function.

For example:

```
>>> import random
>>> def roll_dice():
...     dice_value = random.randint(1,6)
...     print("[in roll_dice] Its a..." + str(dice_value))
...     return dice_value
... 
>>> obtained_dice = roll_dice()
[in roll_dice] Its a...1
>>> print("[outside roll_dice] Its a..." + str(obtained_dice))
[outside roll_dice] Its a...1
```

variable `dice_value` is a local variable inside the function space so you have to return and save it in another variable to continue using it

Answer (score 0):

You can store the return value of your function roll_dice() in a variable that will in return store the value of the return variable (dice_value).

```
random_dice_value = roll_dice()
```

Note: You need to call the function after you have implemented it since Python is an interpreter language. It will execute the file line by line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to call the variable `dice_value` outside of its scope. If you still go on with your one liner print statement, you can do so by calling the function (that's returning the `dice_value` variable) as in:

```
print(roll_dice())
```